Why are Angular Material default styles loaded in such a way as to override custom themes?
I am trying to learn Angular Material, but I'm finding the documentation inaccurate or incomplete. Based on the documentation for version 17, my main toolbar should have a yellow background:
styles.scss:
@use '@angular/material' as mat;

@include mat.core();

$my-primary: mat.define-palette(mat.$yellow-palette);
$my-accent: mat.define-palette(mat.$indigo-palette);
$my-warn: mat.define-palette(mat.$red-palette);

$my-theme: mat.define-light-theme((
  color: (
    primary: $my-primary,
    accent: $my-accent,
    warn: $my-warn,
  ),
  typography: mat.define-typography-config(),
  density: 0
));

@include mat.all-component-themes($my-theme);

angular.json:
"architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            ...
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ]
            ...
          }

Instead, my toolbar's background is light grey. This is because of some  blocks that appear after my theme file is loaded.

Where the heck are these style blocks coming from and why are they being added after the styles defined by the application? Do they expect you to override them using a more specific CSS selector? I'm importing the core theme rules in my scss, so why would Angular Material 17 feel the need to add these styles to begin with?

I found a partial answer, which is that Angular Material 17.3.x uses Material Design 3, not Material Design 2, so the toolbar is supposed to be neutral. But that doesn't answer how they expect you to override this. What is the point of calling mat.core() if they are going to just add a bunch of 
Because you need to add color="primary"
https://v17.material.angular.io/components/toolbar/api


Thanks! That's slick. Wish they would have said something about that in the guides.
